# Не вставляется pdf в html для django

Tags: python, html, css, django, jinja

В общем, мне надо поставить pdf в html, у меня лежит эта pdf в папке /media/ у меня щас вот такой код в html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<embed src="/media/19330269.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
</body>
</html>
```

У меня подключено к путям:
`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Поскажите, может вы видите проблему, потому что через обычный html не для django все работает, спасибо

upd:
Также я еще попробовал написать вот так, в views.py:

```
class ItemAPIViewGet(APIView):

def get(self, request, pdfname):
    pdf = PDF.objects.filter(file=pdfname)

    if not pdf.exists():
        return HttpResponse('404')

    else:
        # file = PDF.objects.get(file=pdfname)
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={pdfname}'
        return response
```

Но тоже не помогает, оно как-то скачивает пустые pdf файлы просто